# SEARCH BY DATE and time in selectbox

Tags: php, date, time

hi i have a table in which i am looking to search previous record with time
i have selectbox with search option  here is the code

```
    if (isset($_REQUEST['searchtype']) && isset($_REQUEST['period']))
    {
    if ($_REQUEST['searchtype'] == "All")
        {
        $period = "All";
        }
    elseif ($_REQUEST['searchtype'] == "Last24hours")
        {
        $period = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')-86400;
        }
    elseif ($_REQUEST['searchtype'] == "Last10days")
        {
        $period = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')-864000;
        }
    elseif ($_REQUEST['searchtype'] == "LastHour")
        {
        $period = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')-3600;
        }
    elseif ($_REQUEST['searchtype'] == "Lastweek")
        {
        $period = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')-604800;
        }
    elseif ($_REQUEST['searchtype'] == "LastMonth")
        {
        $period = date('Y-m-d H:i:s')-2592000;
        }
      else
        {
        $period = $_REQUEST['searchtype'];
        }
```

how would i do this ...

Comment: can't you just set the value in select options to 86400, 86400 .....

Comment: use `strtotime` for easily genrating the timestamps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['searchtype']) && isset($_REQUEST['period']))
{
    $searchtype = $_REQUEST['searchtype'];
    switch($searchtype)
    {
        case 'Last24hours':
            $period = time() - 86400;
        break;
        case 'Last10days':
            $period = time() - 864000;
        break;
        case 'LastHour':
            $period = time() - 3600;
        break;
        case 'Lastweek':
            $period = time() - 604800;
        break;
        case 'LastMonth':
            $period = time() - 2592000;
        break;
        case 'ALL':
        default:
            $period = "All";
    }

    $sql_by_time = ($period != "All") ? " AND time > $period" : "";
}
```

Replace time by what you use in your `SELECT * FROM`

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE YOUR_WHERE
$sql_by_time
```

Comment: i try your code but still confused with the code......
here is my link
http://www.revolutionary-technologies.co.uk/proj/autobodyparts/get-details/details-ebay.php
i want PERIOD select box to search from TIME PORTED COLUMN (2nd last)

Comment: You used `<select name="period" id="period"><option id="All" name="All"  value="All">All</option><option id="3600" name="3600"  value="3600">Last Hour</option>`
You must change that (and all period's options) to `<option id="3600" name="LastHour"  value="Last Hour">Last Hour</option>`
Change the name of options -> LastHour, LastMonth ... If not, change my php code with your names of options

Answer (score 0):

use like this `$period = time() - 86400;`